# Magento2 custom _typography.less gives error

Tags: magento2

I'm attempting to build a theme using Magentos UI library. Per the instructions on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html I have created a _typography.less file for my custom fonts. This fails with the following error.

> Compilation from source:
>
> frontend/mytheme/theme/en_US/css/styles-m.less
>
> .font-face is undefined
>   in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/mytheme/theme/en_US/css/source/_typography.less

the _typography.less file includes

```
.font-face(
    @family-name: 'latoregular',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/lato/lato-regular-webfont',
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal
);

.font-face(
    @family-name: 'latomedium',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/lato/lato-medium-webfont',
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming

> .font-face

to

> .lib-font-face

sorts this issue. Per github the UI library mixins had been renamed. The magento documentation just hadn't been updated to reflect the change.